# Google Calendar JSON API not showing all events

Tags: jquery, json, api, events, google-calendar-api

I've been working with the Google Calendar JSON API, and so far it's working OK.  My only problem is that it's not bringing in all the events, only some of them for no apparent reason.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/weimar.org_cnijr5sa383f7kl28eu63996ec%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&max-results=25&singleevents=false&futureevents=true&sortorder=ascending&orderby=starttime&callback=?",

function(json){

var html = '<ul id="event_feed">';

$.each(json.feed.entry,function(i,entry) {

html += '<li><h3><span class="event_month">' + $.format.date(entry['gd$when'][0].startTime + ' 00:00:00.000', "MMM") + '</span><span class="event_day">' + $.format.date(entry['gd$when'][0].startTime + ' 00:00:00.000', "dd") + '</span></h3><p>' + entry.title.$t + '<br /></p><div class="clear"></div></li>';

})

html += '</ul>';

$('#calendar').html(html);

});
```

You can see what the JSON is outputting, in comparison to the calendar widget (below the JSON output).
http://weimar.edu/news/calendarapi
For example, only one "college days" is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameter set to `max-results=25` - do you have more than 25 events?

Take a look @ [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html).  You might have to page through results with `start-index`

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
max-results=25
```

and

```
futureevents=true
```

Then it will bring all events